# SMTP Mail Sending Issue : com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, smtp-auth

I am trying to send mail from Java.
**If i will send mail to same SMTP it working fine.**
**If i will send mail to outside SMTP means like Gmail, Yahoo etc. it'as shows error like,**

> **[com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay][1]**

**ERROR :**

```
SimpleEmail Start
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay

Mail Send Successfully
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:2064)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1286)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:255)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.nirav.java.project.demo.JavaMailSend.sendEmail(JavaMailSend.java:26)
    at com.nirav.java.project.demo.NewSimpleMail.main(NewSimpleMail.java:34)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1917)
    ... 5 more
```

**Code For Mail Sending :**

```
try {
            System.out.println("SimpleEmail Start");

            String smtpHostServer = "XX.XX.XX.XXX";
            final String toEmail = "XXXXXXXXXX@XXX.XXX";
            final String fromEmail = "XXXXXXXXXX@XXX.XXX";
            final String password = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";

            Properties props = System.getProperties();

            props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHostServer);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25"); //If other then

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
                }
            });
            //Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

          MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

          message.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
          message.addHeader("format", "flowed");
          message.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
          message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("XXXXXX@XXX.XXX", "NoReply-JD"));
          message.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("XXXXXXXXX@XXX.XXX", false));
          message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
          message.setText(body, "UTF-8");
          message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));
          Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Mail Send Successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please help me.
Thnaks.

Comment: As you have said in another comment that it works then you pass the SMTP commands *by hand*, you should use a network dumper like wireshark to control exactly what the java program sends, and what are the differences.

Answer (score 8):

Originally I was about to post this as comment, but it's too long.

The error is quite obvious, you are not allowed to use given SMTP server as relay. ([What are SMTP relays?](https://serverfault.com/questions/325997/what-are-smtp-relays-and-smarthosts))

There are couple of reasons why this can happen:

- You are not authenticated (need to login before sending)
- Recipient is not in list of domains allowed to relay to
- IP address from which you are connecting is not in white list (aka mynetworks in postfix context)

without providing more info (which SMTP server you are using, where are you sending mail, are you authenticated), I guess nobody will help you.

[5.7.1 status code from IANA registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/smtp-enhanced-status-codes/smtp-enhanced-status-codes.xhtml#smtp-enhanced-status-codes-3)

> The sender is not authorized to send to the destination. This can be
> the result of per-host or per-recipient filtering. This memo does not
> discuss the merits of any such filtering, but provides a mechanism to
> report such. This is useful only as a permanent error.

Comment: But if i will login in SMTP server and try to send from it to gmail it's working fine.

But with java code it does't.

Comment: what you meant by `if i will login in SMTP server ` ?

Comment: Means login in SMTP and send it from there only instead of Java Code.

Comment: sorry but what is `from there` ? like from shell using some CLI? or what?

Comment: Like if you login in Gmail and compose new email and send it from there only,
Instead of send mail by your java code.

Comment: @rkosegi thanks, your answer helped me with my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264254/java-send-mail-relay-access-denied-error

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem also but it was intermittent.
We have 2 servers that are within a cluster and on one the ip address of system that sends the email was not defined correctly.
Unfortunately the error message "javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses is confusing.
the 2nd error message: "com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 relay not permitted" matches much better.